# Can't work out what is wrong with the code for my basic Android App

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Here is my corrected code that still is not working, I've also included the logcat this time to help identify my error.  Again thanks for the amazing response to my last request;

```
package com.example.michaelheneghan.example1;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
import android.widget.EditText;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements    GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
    GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener{
//change back to TextView
    private Button mikesButton;
    private TextView mikesText;
    private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetector;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ////////// Layout object is added //////////////////
    RelativeLayout myLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);


    ////////// Button object being created /////////////////
    this.mikesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mikesButton);
    this.mikesButton.setText("Click Me");
    this.mikesButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    this.mikesText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mikesText);



    ///////// Set up an event listener for the button //////////////
    this.mikesButton.setOnClickListener(  /// listen for an event on this button
            new Button.OnClickListener() {   //// Interface
                public void onClick(View v) {    //// Callback method
                    TextView Change = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mikesButton);
                    Change.setText("Good job, it changed!");
                }
            }
    );


    ///////////// Listening for multiple events ////////////////////
    mikesButton.setOnLongClickListener(
            new Button.OnLongClickListener(){   //// Interface
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {    //// Callback method
                    TextView Change = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mikesText);
                    Change.setText("Good job, it changed when you held onto the button!");
                    return true;
                }
            }
    );


    //////////// Set up an event listener for a double tap event //////////////
    mikesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mikesButton); /////// Reference to the button
    this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this); /// an object from GD class to detect gestures
    gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this); /// Set method to detect double taps


    ///////// Input object called mikesText is added //////////////////////

    //mikesText.setId(2);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textdeets = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

    ///////// Give rules to position widgets ////////////////////////
    textdeets.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, mikesButton.getId()); /// Place above the button that is already centered//
    textdeets.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL); //// place in the middle of the screen ////
    textdeets.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 50); ///// where to place; left, top, right, bottom ///////


    ////////////// Rules of where to place the layout object ///////////////
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonDeets = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );


    //////////// Rules of where to place the button object ////////////////
    buttonDeets.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    buttonDeets.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);


    ////////// Add widgets to layout and their rules///////////
    myLayout.addView(mikesButton, buttonDeets); //Second param shows android the rules of how it is layed out
    myLayout.addView(mikesText, textdeets);

}

////////////// implement gesture methods from GestureDetector class ///////////////////////

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
    mikesButton.setText("onDoubleTap");  /// set message to change text on screen to whatever gesture just occured
    return true; // return true on all gesture methods so the system shows the event was handled
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
    mikesButton.setText("onSingleTapConfirmed");  /// set message to change text on screen to whatever gesture just occured
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    mikesButton.setText("onDoubleTapEvent");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    mikesButton.setText("onDown");
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    mikesButton.setText("onSingleTapUp");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    mikesButton.setText("onScroll");
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    mikesButton.setText("onFling");
    return true;
}


////////// Override default method so that system checks if the event is a gesture before checking for common event /////////////
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    this.gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event); /// add the gesture detector variable to check for
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Main xml is:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/stringMessage"
    android:id="@+id/mikesText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/buttonName"
    android:id="@+id/mikesButton"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/mikesText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/mikesText" />
```

The logcat I'm getting is;

```
10-09 11:16:47.471    5464-5464/com.example.michaelheneghan.example1 I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
10-09 11:16:47.471    5464-5464/com.example.michaelheneghan.example1 I/art﹕ Late-enabling JIT
10-09 11:16:47.473    5464-5464/com.example.michaelheneghan.example1 I/art﹕ JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
10-09 11:16:47.497    5464-5464/com.example.michaelheneghan.example1 W/System﹕ ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.michaelheneghan.example1-2/lib/x86
10-09 11:16:47.599    5464-5464/com.example.michaelheneghan.example1 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-09 11:16:47.599    5464-5464/com.example.michaelheneghan.example1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.michaelheneghan.example1, PID: 5464
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.michaelheneghan.example1/com.example.michaelheneghan.example1.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4309)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4145)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4117)
            at com.example.michaelheneghan.example1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:105)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: why all time you reinitiating mikesButton it need to be done only once if you use findviewbyid you dont need to do new Button(this) please got through android doc https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing i see is that you are using the same resource id for a button and textview (R.id.mikesButton) :

```
mikesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mikesButton); /// ref to the location by id

public boolean onLongClick(View v) {    //// Callback method
     TextView Change = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mikesButton);
     Change.setText("Good job, it changed when you held onto the button!");
     return true;
}
```

Which at some point should give you a cast exception. A LogCat as @geert-berkers would be of great help.

**Edit**

---

This is worthless :

```
Button mikesButton = new Button(this);
mikesButton.setText("Click Me");
mikesButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
//mikesButton.setId(1);
```

Since it's never added to a layout and besides you are just a line after inflating the buttom from the xml layout activity_main :

`mikesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mikesButton); /// ref to the location` by id

To resume it should be :

```
Button mikesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mikesButton);
mikesButton.setText("Click Me");
mikesButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
//mikesButton.setId(1); <-- never do this when inflating from xml R.id.mikesButton is already the id
```

Other error is that you are never setting the properties mikesButton, mikesText and this is why :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    Button mikesButton = new Button(this); //<-- this means you are using a local to the method an not the class property you define
    ...
}
```

It should be :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    this.mikesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mikesButton);
    this.mikesText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mikesText); <-- Notice that i chaged the id so it should be changed on the activity_main layout
    ...
}
```

You already set the layout using :

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

so doing this later :

```
/////// Sets this activities content to this view & change background color //////////
setContentView(myLayout);
```

will replace the layout you loaded from the xml with the one you are making dynamicly so all the views that you loaded from the xml are not on the activity layout no more.

To resume all the changes :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ////////// Button object being created /////////////////
    this.mikesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mikesButton); /// ref to the location by id
    this.mikesButton.setText("Click Me");
    this.mikesButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    ///////// Input object called mikesText is added //////////////////////
    this.mikesText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mikesText);


    ///////// Set up an event listener for the button //////////////
    this.mikesButton.setOnClickListener(  /// listen for an event on this button
            new Button.OnClickListener() {   //// Interface
                public void onClick(View v) {    //// Callback method
                    MainActivity.this.mikesText.setText("Good job, it changed!");
                }
            }
    );


    ///////////// Listening for multiple events ////////////////////
    this.mikesButton.setOnLongClickListener(
            new Button.OnLongClickListener() {   //// Interface
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {    //// Callback method
                    MainActivity.this.mikesText.setText("Good job, it changed when you held onto the button!");
                    return true;
                }
            }
    );


    //////////// Set up an event listener for a double tap event //////////////
    this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this); /// an object from GD class to detect gestures
    this.gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this); /// Set method to detect double taps


    //TODO: if you want to add a button from code
    Button otherButton = new Button(this);
    otherButton.setText("Hey i was made by code");
    otherButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    ////////////// Rules of where to place the layout object ///////////////
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonDeets = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

    //////////// Rules of where to place the button object ////////////////
    buttonDeets.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    buttonDeets.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    RelativeLayout mainLayout = this.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout); //<-- you have to set the id property of the RelativeLayout on the xml file
    mainLayout.addView(otherButton,buttonDeets);

}
```

And the layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mikesButton"
        android:text="Button to press"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Text to change"
        android:id="@+id/mikesText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mikesButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

@geert-berkers i stole your xml cause too lazy to make one myself :p

### **Edit 2 : Changed question**

The error you are having now it's because of  :

```
////////// Add widgets to layout and their rules///////////
myLayout.addView(mikesButton, buttonDeets); //Second param shows android the rules of how it is layed out
myLayout.addView(mikesText, textdeets);
```

Here you are saying that you want to add mikesButton and mikesText to myLayout that you created from code... but the button is already part of the layout that you loaded from the xml (with `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`).
I don't understand what are you trying to achieve by doing this. If what you want to do is to add new views by code don't use `findViewById(R.id.mikesButton);` but create a new instance using `new Button(this)`. findViewById tries to find a view that is already in the hierarchy of a viewgroup, in this case the viewgroup is the layout of your activity.
Look at the //TODO: part of the code i gave you and notice is not the same that what you are doing here.
Also avoid using the same reference on different objects cause you are gonna get confuse at some moment.

Don't :

```
this.mikesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mikesButton);
// Later ...
this.mikesButton = new Button(this);
// So now you lost the reference to the previous object
```

Instead Do :

```
this.mikesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mikesButton);
// Later ...
Button otherButton = new Button(this);
// You can still reference the precious object and u know that mikesButton is the one you loaded from the xml layout
```

Comment: Thanks very much I wasn't expecting such a quick and comprehensive answer.  Everything you say makes sense, its hard to piece all the different gestures together when you look at them in separate tutorials without fully understanding how they link.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Kalem, I have made the changes you suggested but I am still getting errors Geert removed all of the layout rules which I do not want to do.  So my code now looks like this:

Comment: Please don't change the question subject... It changes the context of the given answers. You can ask another question and link an user so he can help you using @ follow with the name of the user (i.e @Kalem) or just use an Edit indication to let us know u changed something on the question.

Comment: I edited my answer to complete with the error you are having now

Comment: Got it working now Kalem, a massive thank you. As you say I'm trying to set the layout in code when I have already done it in xml so it's causing it to crash.

Answer (score 2):

Could you post the error whole log?

That gives us much more information!
There you can see what went wrong, and even where.

For example:

```
04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple.SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.onCreate(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java:68)
    04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

**Edit**

I tried your code and this is the error:

```
10-08 14:36:18.350 28294-28294/geert.berkers.bridgetimer E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
10-08 14:36:18.350 28294-28294/geert.berkers.bridgetimer E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3337)
10-08 14:36:18.350 28294-28294/geert.berkers.bridgetimer E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3208)
10-08 14:36:18.350 28294-28294/geert.berkers.bridgetimer E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3188)
10-08 14:36:18.350 28294-28294/geert.berkers.bridgetimer E/AndroidRuntime:     at geert.berkers.bridgetimer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:103)
10-08 14:36:18.350 28294-28294/geert.berkers.bridgetimer E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
```

It crashes when you add the button to the layout.

**Edit 2**

One more thing I see, is that you use 'setContentView(layout)' twice.
In my opinion (Not Android Expert!) you should set only the layout once, and use the activity_main.xml for this one! Don't do it programmatically.

I deleted the layouts, and used @Kalem 's answer. Now its works fine for me.

Code that works:

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements   GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
        GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

    private Button mikesButton;
    private TextView mikesText;
    private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetector;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ////////// Layout object is added //////////////////
        //RelativeLayout myLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);


        ////////// Button object being created /////////////////
        mikesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mikesButton); /// ref to the location by id
        mikesButton.setText("Click Me");
        mikesButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        //mikesButton.setId(1);


        ///////// Set up an event listener for the button //////////////

        mikesButton.setOnClickListener(  /// listen for an event on this button
                new Button.OnClickListener() {   //// Interface
                    public void onClick(View v) {    //// Callback method
                        TextView Change = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mikesText);
                        Change.setText("Good job, it changed!");
                    }
                }
        );


        ///////////// Listening for multiple events ////////////////////
        mikesButton.setOnLongClickListener(
                new Button.OnLongClickListener() {   //// Interface
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {    //// Callback method
                        TextView Change = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mikesText);
                        Change.setText("Good job, it changed when you held onto the button!");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
        );


        //////////// Set up an event listener for a double tap event //////////////
        mikesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mikesButton); /////// Reference to the button
        this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this); /// an object from GD class to detect gestures
        gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this); /// Set method to detect double taps


        ///////// Input object called mikesText is added //////////////////////
        TextView mikesText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mikesText);
        //mikesText.setId(2);

/*
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textdeets = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        ///////// Give rules to position widgets ////////////////////////
        textdeets.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, mikesButton.getId()); /// Place above the button that is already centered//
        textdeets.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL); //// place in the middle of the screen ////
        textdeets.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 50); ///// where to place; left, top, right, bottom ///////


        ////////////// Rules of where to place the layout object ///////////////
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonDeets = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );


        //////////// Rules of where to place the button object ////////////////
        buttonDeets.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        buttonDeets.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);


        ////////// Add widgets to layout and their rules///////////
        myLayout.addView(mikesButton, buttonDeets); //Second param shows android the rules of how it is layed out
        myLayout.addView(mikesText, textdeets);


        /////// Sets this activities content to this view & change background color //////////
        setContentView(myLayout);
        myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
*/

    }

////////////// implement gesture methods from GestureDetector class ///////////////////////

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        mikesButton.setText("onDoubleTap");  /// set message to change text on screen to whatever gesture just occured
        return true; // return true on all gesture methods so the system shows the event was handled
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        mikesButton.setText("onSingleTapConfirmed");  /// set message to change text on screen to whatever gesture just occured
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        mikesButton.setText("onDoubleTapEvent");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        mikesButton.setText("onDown");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        mikesButton.setText("onSingleTapUp");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        mikesButton.setText("onScroll");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        mikesButton.setText("onFling");
        return true;
    }


    ////////// Override default method so that system checks if the event is a gesture before checking for common event /////////////
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        this.gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event); /// add the gesture detector variable to check for
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And I created a simple activity_main.xml file with button and text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mikesButton"
        android:text="Button to press"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Text to change"
        android:id="@+id/mikesText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mikesButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: And thank @Kalem for his tips. I haven't seen he used the Button id for the Textview